# Android chromecast: how to detect cast state on app start, before the app has been backgrounded?

Tags: android, chromecast

I'm adding Chromecast support to an existing Android app. My app should detect the cast state and change part of its display accordingly.

My current code works, except that it detects the cast state incorrectly in one specific case:

1. A cast device is available, and the app is closed (not in the
   background).
2. A user opens the app.
3. The cast state detected by my app *should* be NOT_CONNECTED, but it's actually NO_DEVICES_AVAILABLE.
4. After waiting several seconds, the cast state is still wrong.
5. After backgrounding the app and foregrounding it again, the cast state is correct.

I believe my problem is caused by Google Cast's [documented behavior](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/integrate#configure_device_discovery):

> CastContext holds a reference to the MediaRouter internally, and **will start the discovery process when the sender app enters the foreground**, and stop when the sender app enters background.

On startup, I register a cast state listener, and I also check the cast state:

```kotlin
CastHelper {
  private val context: CastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(activity).apply {
    addCastStateListener(this@CastHelper)
  }

  val castState = context.castState

  override fun onCastStateChanged(p0: Int) {
    println("cast state change detected: new state is $castState") 
    // ^ this prints correctly, except during steps 2-4 when it never prints at all
  }
}
```

I thought maybe the cast state listener was the problem, so I tried manually checking the cast state every second. Nothing changed; the `castState` is still `NO_DEVICES_AVAILABLE` when it should be `NOT_CONNECTED`.

How can my app can detect the cast state even if it hasn't been backgrounded? If there's no way to do that, then is casting from any app impossible until the app has been backgrounded?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was that CastHelper was initialized lazily, long after the app started. CastHelper only adds itself as a CastStateListener on initialization, so we weren't detecting cast state changes until then.

To fix it, I created a no-op method on CastHelper:

```kotlin
CastHelper {
  ...

  fun onCreate() {}
}
```

And called it in my app activity's onCreate method:

```kotlin
class AppActivity : FragmentActivity() {
  public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    ...
    CastHelper.onCreate()
}
```

This forces the CastHelper to be initialized whenever the app is running, and allows the app to correctly detect the cast state.